# How to save or edit javascript files in ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I want to use the Ace editor to save and edit javascript files
it's not clear in the documentation how to do that.

Comment: Where are you going to save these files to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ace editor is only the UI part of the editor. Think of it as: `like a textarea but cool!`.
To deal with files you need some kind of server that will read and save the files and will send the text to the webpage where Ace lives. (You can also use html5 filesystem api, but that only works on chrome).
You can find many interesting implementations of this in [Zed](http://zedapp.org/) source code at https://github.com/zedapp/zed/tree/master/app/js/fs, which is a code editor based on Ace.

Comment: what do you think about using local storage as a means to store code as the user types but store it on the server only when the user s navigating away from the page or explicitly hits the save button

Comment: localStorage is rather slow, especially for users without ssd, so make sure you do not save to it on every keystroke

Comment: i guess a debounce function or a function similar to codepen where x number of changes would be better, i guess 2nd one s more customizable and has no timeouts

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a button called download, this is how you would do it

I am using the filesaver.js library that you can find [HERE](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      var file = new File([editor.getValue()], "zup.js", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
      saveAs(file);
})
```