# Can I open an HTML file in Ace Editor?

Tags: html, ace-editor

I do not know if a pre saved HTML file can be opened in Ace Editor. Is this possible?

In fact I want to load a pre saved HTML file in the Ace editor so that the code of the file can be viewed in the editor.

Please tell me the way to do this.

Comment: yes, why not? since its build for developers. and they mention *Syntax highlighting for over 110 languages (TextMate/Sublime Text.tmlanguage files can be imported)* [here..](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463106/how-to-save-or-edit-javascript-files-in-ace-editor/25466796#25466796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I have used PHP to do this.

```
<div id="editor">
<?php echo htmlentities(file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "html_file_address_here"));?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes u can do it

`var editor = ace.edit('left_main_content'); // Area with html ... or try its parent

```
    editor.setOptions({  
   theme: "ace/theme/dawn",     
   mode: "ace/mode/html",   
   setUseWrapMode: true,
```

})`