# Ace Editor save as txt file

Tags: ace-editor

I have incorporated ace editor in my project

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <pre id="editor">
    </pre>
</div>  

<script src="src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/text");
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);

    $('#mode').on('change', function(){
        console.log("Change");
        var newMode = document.getElementById('mode').value
        console.log(newMode);
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/" + newMode);
    });
</script>
```

I want to store the contents written on this editor as a text file using php or javascript.
Need help on this.
Thanks in advance.
Cheers :)

Comment: Have you searched for similar questions before posting this one? I am tempted to vote to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463106/how-to-save-or-edit-javascript-files-in-ace-editor/25466796

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented download file from ACE editor using Controller.

```
 <div id="editor"></div>
        <form action="downloadFromAce" method="post">
            <textarea type="text" hidden id="valueInput" name=value ></textarea>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="downloadBtn" type="submit">Download</button>
        </form>
```

And on click of download button send this data (setting data in text area using jquery) form ACE editor to controller on POST request.

```
<script>
let editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/yaml");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#downloadBtn").click(function () {
        const data = editor.getValue();
        $("#valueInput").val(data);
    })
})
```

```
@PostMapping("/download") 
Public void downloadFile(@ModelAttribute DownloadFileContent fileContent,HttpServletResponse response){
 try{
   response.setContentType("text/plain");
   response.setHeader("content-Disposition","attachment;filename=demo.txt");
   InputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getValue().getBytes());
   IOUtils.copy(is,response.getOutputStream());
   response.flushBuffer();
  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace(); 
 }
 }     
}
```

I have used spring boot for backend. But you can do that using other language also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example of how to save a file, with a particular extension based on the selected mode.

1. Populate the mode selection box
2. Enter text you wish to save
3. Click the "Save" button in the toolbar
4. Enter a filename; a default file extension will be provided, based on the mode
5. Confirm
6. A dialog will be presented asking where to save the file

I used the following libraries:

- jQuery - ace-editor requires it
- tingle - nice light-weight plain js modal windows
- FileSaver - an HTML5 saveAs() FileSaver implementation

```js
const MODES = getModes();

ace.config.set('basePath', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.11');

$('select[name="sel-mode"]').append(MODES.map(mode => new Option(mode.text, mode.value)));

const defaultMode = 'text';
const editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode(`ace/mode/${defaultMode}`);
editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);

$('select[name="sel-mode"]').on('change', function(e) {
  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/" + e.target.value);
}).val(defaultMode);

$('button[name="btn-save"]').on('click', e => saveDialog.open());

const saveDialog = new tingle.modal({
  footer: true,
  stickyFooter: false,
  closeMethods: ['overlay', 'button', 'escape'],
  closeLabel: 'Close',
  cssClass: ['dialog-save'],
  onOpen: function() {
    $('input[name="filename"]').val(`*.${lookupFileExtension()}`);
  },
  onClose: function() {},
  beforeClose: function() {
    return true;
  }
});

saveDialog.addFooterBtn('Confirm', 'tingle-btn tingle-btn--primary tingle-btn--pull-right', function() {
  const filename = $('input[name="filename"]').val();
  const file = new File([editor.getValue()], filename, {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
  });
  saveAs(file);
  saveDialog.close();
});

saveDialog.addFooterBtn('Cancel', 'tingle-btn tingle-btn--danger tingle-btn--pull-right', function() {
  saveDialog.close();
});

saveDialog.setContent($('<div>')
  .append($('<h1>', {
    text: 'Enter a filename'
  }))
  .append($('<input>', {
    name: 'filename'
  })).unwrap().html());

function lookupFileExtension() {
  const selectedMode = $('select[name="sel-mode"]').val();
  const mode = MODES.find(currMode => currMode.value === selectedMode);
  return mode.extension || mode.value;
}

// TODO: Extensions need some more work.
// Option text/values via: https://ace.c9.io/tool/mode_creator.html
function getModes() {
  return [{
    "text": "ABAP",
    "value": "abap"
  }, {
    "text": "ABC",
    "value": "abc"
  }, {
    "text": "ActionScript",
    "value": "actionscript",
    "extension": "as"
  }, {
    "text": "ADA",
    "value": "ada"
  }, {
    "text": "Alda",
    "value": "alda"
  }, {
    "text": "Apache Conf",
    "value": "apache_conf"
  }, {
    "text": "Apex",
    "value": "apex"
  }, {
    "text": "AQL",
    "value": "aql"
  }, {
    "text": "AsciiDoc",
    "value": "asciidoc"
  }, {
    "text": "ASL",
    "value": "asl"
  }, {
    "text": "Assembly x86",
    "value": "assembly_x86"
  }, {
    "text": "AutoHotkey / AutoIt",
    "value": "autohotkey",
    "extension": "ahk"
  }, {
    "text": "BatchFile",
    "value": "batchfile",
    "extension": "bat"
  }, {
    "text": "C and C++",
    "value": "c_cpp",
    "extension": "cpp"
  }, {
    "text": "C9Search",
    "value": "c9search"
  }, {
    "text": "Cirru",
    "value": "cirru"
  }, {
    "text": "Clojure",
    "value": "clojure",
    "extension": "clj"
  }, {
    "text": "Cobol",
    "value": "cobol",
    "extension": "cob"
  }, {
    "text": "CoffeeScript",
    "value": "coffee"
  }, {
    "text": "ColdFusion",
    "value": "coldfusion",
    "extension": "cfm"
  }, {
    "text": "Crystal",
    "value": "crystal",
    "extension": "rpt"
  }, {
    "text": "C#",
    "value": "csharp",
    "extension": "cs"
  }, {
    "text": "Csound Document",
    "value": "csound_document",
    "extension": "csd"
  }, {
    "text": "Csound",
    "value": "csound_orchestra",
    "extension": "csd"
  }, {
    "text": "Csound Score",
    "value": "csound_score",
    "extension": "csd"
  }, {
    "text": "CSS",
    "value": "css"
  }, {
    "text": "Curly",
    "value": "curly"
  }, {
    "text": "D",
    "value": "d"
  }, {
    "text": "Dart",
    "value": "dart"
  }, {
    "text": "Diff",
    "value": "diff"
  }, {
    "text": "Dockerfile",
    "value": "dockerfile"
  }, {
    "text": "Dot",
    "value": "dot"
  }, {
    "text": "Drools",
    "value": "drools",
    "extension": "drl"
  }, {
    "text": "Edifact",
    "value": "edifact",
    "extension": "edi"
  }, {
    "text": "Eiffel",
    "value": "eiffel",
    "extension": "e"
  }, {
    "text": "EJS",
    "value": "ejs"
  }, {
    "text": "Elixir",
    "value": "elixir",
    "extension": "ex"
  }, {
    "text": "Elm",
    "value": "elm"
  }, {
    "text": "Erlang",
    "value": "erlang",
    "extension": "erl"
  }, {
    "text": "Forth",
    "value": "forth",
    "extension": "4th"
  }, {
    "text": "Fortran",
    "value": "fortran",
    "extension": "f90"
  }, {
    "text": "FSharp",
    "value": "fsharp",
    "extension": "fs"
  }, {
    "text": "FSL",
    "value": "fsl"
  }, {
    "text": "FreeMarker",
    "value": "ftl"
  }, {
    "text": "Gcode",
    "value": "gcode"
  }, {
    "text": "Gherkin",
    "value": "gherkin"
  }, {
    "text": "Gitignore",
    "value": "gitignore"
  }, {
    "text": "Glsl",
    "value": "glsl"
  }, {
    "text": "Gobstones",
    "value": "gobstones"
  }, {
    "text": "Go",
    "value": "golang",
    "extension": "go"
  }, {
    "text": "GraphQLSchema",
    "value": "graphqlschema"
  }, {
    "text": "Groovy",
    "value": "groovy"
  }, {
    "text": "HAML",
    "value": "haml"
  }, {
    "text": "Handlebars",
    "value": "handlebars",
    "extension": "hbs"
  }, {
    "text": "Haskell",
    "value": "haskell",
    "extension": "hs"
  }, {
    "text": "Haskell Cabal",
    "value": "haskell_cabal",
    "extension": "hs"
  }, {
    "text": "haXe",
    "value": "haxe"
  }, {
    "text": "Hjson",
    "value": "hjson"
  }, {
    "text": "HTML",
    "value": "html"
  }, {
    "text": "HTML (Elixir)",
    "value": "html_elixir"
  }, {
    "text": "HTML (Ruby)",
    "value": "html_ruby"
  }, {
    "text": "INI",
    "value": "ini"
  }, {
    "text": "Io",
    "value": "io"
  }, {
    "text": "Jack",
    "value": "jack"
  }, {
    "text": "Jade",
    "value": "jade"
  }, {
    "text": "Java",
    "value": "java"
  }, {
    "text": "JavaScript",
    "value": "javascript",
    "extension": "js"
  }, {
    "text": "JSON",
    "value": "json",
    "extension": "json"
  }, {
    "text": "JSON5",
    "value": "json5",
    "extension": "json"
  }, {
    "text": "JSONiq",
    "value": "jsoniq"
  }, {
    "text": "JSP",
    "value": "jsp",
    "extension": "jsp"
  }, {
    "text": "JSSM",
    "value": "jssm"
  }, {
    "text": "JSX",
    "value": "jsx"
  }, {
    "text": "Julia",
    "value": "julia"
  }, {
    "text": "Kotlin",
    "value": "kotlin"
  }, {
    "text": "LaTeX",
    "value": "latex",
    "extension": "tex"
  }, {
    "text": "LESS",
    "value": "less"
  }, {
    "text": "Liquid",
    "value": "liquid"
  }, {
    "text": "Lisp",
    "value": "lisp"
  }, {
    "text": "LiveScript",
    "value": "livescript"
  }, {
    "text": "LogiQL",
    "value": "logiql"
  }, {
    "text": "LSL",
    "value": "lsl"
  }, {
    "text": "Lua",
    "value": "lua"
  }, {
    "text": "LuaPage",
    "value": "luapage"
  }, {
    "text": "Lucene",
    "value": "lucene"
  }, {
    "text": "Makefile",
    "value": "makefile"
  }, {
    "text": "Markdown",
    "value": "markdown"
  }, {
    "text": "Mask",
    "value": "mask"
  }, {
    "text": "MATLAB",
    "value": "matlab"
  }, {
    "text": "Maze",
    "value": "maze"
  }, {
    "text": "MediaWiki",
    "value": "mediawiki"
  }, {
    "text": "MEL",
    "value": "mel"
  }, {
    "text": "MIXAL",
    "value": "mixal"
  }, {
    "text": "MUSHCode",
    "value": "mushcode"
  }, {
    "text": "MySQL",
    "value": "mysql",
    "extension": "sql"
  }, {
    "text": "Nginx",
    "value": "nginx"
  }, {
    "text": "Nim",
    "value": "nim"
  }, {
    "text": "Nix",
    "value": "nix"
  }, {
    "text": "NSIS",
    "value": "nsis"
  }, {
    "text": "Nunjucks",
    "value": "nunjucks"
  }, {
    "text": "Objective-C",
    "value": "objectivec"
  }, {
    "text": "OCaml",
    "value": "ocaml"
  }, {
    "text": "Pascal",
    "value": "pascal",
    "extension": "pas"
  }, {
    "text": "Perl",
    "value": "perl",
    "extension": "pl"
  }, {
    "text": "Perl 6",
    "value": "perl6",
    "extension": "pl"
  }, {
    "text": "pgSQL",
    "value": "pgsql"
  }, {
    "text": "PHP",
    "value": "php"
  }, {
    "text": "PHP (Blade Template)",
    "value": "php_laravel_blade",
    "extension": "php"
  }, {
    "text": "Pig",
    "value": "pig"
  }, {
    "text": "Powershell",
    "value": "powershell"
  }, {
    "text": "Praat",
    "value": "praat"
  }, {
    "text": "Prisma",
    "value": "prisma"
  }, {
    "text": "Prolog",
    "value": "prolog"
  }, {
    "text": "Properties",
    "value": "properties"
  }, {
    "text": "Protobuf",
    "value": "protobuf"
  }, {
    "text": "Puppet",
    "value": "puppet"
  }, {
    "text": "Python",
    "value": "python",
    "extension": "py"
  }, {
    "text": "QML",
    "value": "qml"
  }, {
    "text": "R",
    "value": "r"
  }, {
    "text": "Razor",
    "value": "razor"
  }, {
    "text": "RDoc",
    "value": "rdoc"
  }, {
    "text": "Red",
    "value": "red"
  }, {
    "text": "RHTML",
    "value": "rhtml"
  }, {
    "text": "RST",
    "value": "rst"
  }, {
    "text": "Ruby",
    "value": "ruby"
  }, {
    "text": "Rust",
    "value": "rust"
  }, {
    "text": "SASS",
    "value": "sass"
  }, {
    "text": "SCAD",
    "value": "scad"
  }, {
    "text": "Scala",
    "value": "scala"
  }, {
    "text": "Scheme",
    "value": "scheme"
  }, {
    "text": "SCSS",
    "value": "scss"
  }, {
    "text": "SH",
    "value": "sh"
  }, {
    "text": "SJS",
    "value": "sjs"
  }, {
    "text": "Slim",
    "value": "slim"
  }, {
    "text": "Smarty",
    "value": "smarty"
  }, {
    "text": "snippets",
    "value": "snippets"
  }, {
    "text": "Soy Template",
    "value": "soy_template"
  }, {
    "text": "Space",
    "value": "space"
  }, {
    "text": "SQL",
    "value": "sql"
  }, {
    "text": "SQLServer",
    "value": "sqlserver"
  }, {
    "text": "Stylus",
    "value": "stylus"
  }, {
    "text": "SVG",
    "value": "svg"
  }, {
    "text": "Swift",
    "value": "swift"
  }, {
    "text": "Tcl",
    "value": "tcl"
  }, {
    "text": "Terraform",
    "value": "terraform"
  }, {
    "text": "Tex",
    "value": "tex"
  }, {
    "text": "Text",
    "value": "text",
    "extension": "txt"
  }, {
    "text": "Textile",
    "value": "textile"
  }, {
    "text": "Toml",
    "value": "toml"
  }, {
    "text": "TSX",
    "value": "tsx"
  }, {
    "text": "Twig",
    "value": "twig"
  }, {
    "text": "Typescript",
    "value": "typescript",
    "extension": "ts"
  }, {
    "text": "Vala",
    "value": "vala"
  }, {
    "text": "VBScript",
    "value": "vbscript"
  }, {
    "text": "Velocity",
    "value": "velocity"
  }, {
    "text": "Verilog",
    "value": "verilog"
  }, {
    "text": "VHDL",
    "value": "vhdl"
  }, {
    "text": "Visualforce",
    "value": "visualforce"
  }, {
    "text": "Wollok",
    "value": "wollok"
  }, {
    "text": "XML",
    "value": "xml"
  }, {
    "text": "XQuery",
    "value": "xquery"
  }, {
    "text": "YAML",
    "value": "yaml",
    "extension": "yml"
  }, {
    "text": "Zeek",
    "value": "zeek"
  }, {
    "text": "Django",
    "value": "django"
  }];
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.toolbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 2em;
  background: #111;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
}

.toolbar button,
.toolbar select {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.67em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  align-self: center;
}

#editor {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 3.33em);
}

.dialog-save h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.dialog-save .tingle-modal-box__content {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.dialog-save .tingle-modal-box__footer {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.dialog-save .tingle-btn {
  padding: 0.667rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tingle/0.15.2/tingle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tingle/0.15.2/tingle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.11/ace.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.11/theme-monokai.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.11/mode-text.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-saver@2.0.2/dist/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <select name="sel-mode"></select>
    <button name="btn-save">Save</button>
  </div>
  <pre id="editor"></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" id="input-fileName" value="Result" placeholder="Enter file name">
  <button id="download2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("download2").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
 var filename = $("#input-fileName").val()
  var file = new File([editor.getValue()],filename +".h4c", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
  saveAs(file);
```

})
    

Define a button as shown in  the code which will trigger the function and the function gets the user input from ace editor and process it to a file with extension, by default i have set extension to .h4c change it according to your need and for the filename i have provided textbox.

Comment: Please edit to include an explanation of why this works.

Comment: you code nee editing... check character out of highligh box